# How to find latest Sybase ASE queries within DB?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a PB application connecting to Sybase ASE; Is there a way we can trace the DB calls when the application is running.
I used to do that in Oracle 10/11G but unable to figure out in sybase ase.
It will be immensely helpful if I am able to run a module in PB application and check the queries executed after that.
I am using either DBVisualizer or RapidSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MDA tables. For example, monSysStatement and monSysSQLText. See the ASE documentation and/or www.sypron.nl/mda.

Comment: thanks a lot, this seems to be the answer for me, but I am having role issue and getting error '" You must have any of the following role(s) to execute this command/procedure: 'mon_role' . Please contact a user with the appropriate role for help."  will try to fix this first.

Comment: You need to have sso_role to grant mon_role. If you cannot do that yourself, ask your DBA.